# Blender 3.2, Mac 1 Pro, Cycles, GPU Rendering outputs only part of the frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, osx

A desperate cry for help:) Newbie. Trying to render an animation using internal GPU (Mac 1 Pro) & Cycles (Blender 3.2). As a result I get ragged frames with huge black areas below (only the top of the frame is rendered). I got identical results for different output file formats: neither png neither FFmpeg video worked. Example of the frame and interface screenshot are attached (also I can share the example of the output video if it would help but it's quite similar to the screenshot).

I couldn't find the answer in Google. Most relevant were the tile issues in old versions, but [as I understood] it isn't the issue anymore. I still tried to manipulate with the tile's amount and it even worked one time randomly and I almost got the full one frame (still there was a little negative space below). But on the next frame in sequence it didn't work so I guess that's not where the problem hides.

I do not have this kind of problem at all with the CPU device selected for rendering.

Could you please help me and explain what exactly I set wrong and how to fix this so I could use GPU for proper rendering? [ps I am 100% sure I haven't done anything with the render region]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert for Mac or GPUs in general, but since this problem doesn't exist when you render with CPU this sounds like there is a problem with the GPU. But since I don't know anything about Mac - is Mac 1 Pro all the information needed in terms of hardware or do you have more specifications which might be helpful to analyze this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately that's all the info. I can only add the detailed description of the integrated card: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Apple-M1-Pro-16-Core-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.581797.0.html